# ok this has happened twice... i need reassurance

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, reading-hands, hand

Player 1: has 7,7 both cards black
Player 2: has K diamond 3 spades

Flop all diamonds Includes Ace.

Player 1 swears it's split because the flop has ace high. I tried to explain the best 5 cards are including the king from player 2.   Am I right? Who wins please explain.

Comment: your friend needs to learn to read hands, you are correct the king plays.

Comment: `swears it's split because the flop has ace high.`  Even ignoring Player 1's lack of hand-reading ability I find it a bit disturbing that they are already trying to split the pot when there are two remaining cards to come!

Comment: If by "flop" you mean the whole board of 5 cards are all diamonds, then yes, your K wins. Poker hands have five cards, and all five count.

Answer (score 0):

`Kd 3s` beats `7c 7s` on a `Ad Xd Xd Xd Xd` board, you are correct.

The player with `Kd 3s` has `Ad Kd Xd Xd Xd`, an A-K high flush.

The player with `7c 7s` has `Ad Xd Xd Xd Xd`, an A-X high flush (and X can never be greater than K in this example.

As you suggest, it's all about the best 5 card hand, so `2d 3s` vs `7c 7s` on a `Ad Td 6d 4d 3d` board for example would be a chop, because the `2d` in the player's hand does not improve their flush - both players have a 5 card hand of `Ad Td 6d 4d 3d`.